# Is it necessary to synchronize the methods that read a list without modifying it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to synchonization. I know that when I'm trying with multithread I can have issues adding thing to a list. For instance with the following code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class MySafeList extends ArrayList<Double>{

    static ArrayList<Double> mySafeList;

    public boolean add(Double d){
        mySafeList.add(d);
        return true;
    }

    public int size(){
        return mySafeList.size();
    }

    public Double get(int i){
        return mySafeList.get(i);

    }

    static boolean stressTest(int n, int m){
        Thread threads[] = new Thread[n]; 
        try{
            for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
                threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1));
                threads[i].start();
                for(int j=0; j<m;j++){
                    Double d = new Double((double) j);
                    mySafeList.add(d);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }catch(Exception e){
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySafeList safeList = new MySafeList();
        stressTest(2,4);    
    }

}
```

I want to add the synchronization primitives to the `add ()` method, **is it necessary to synchronize the methods that read the list without modifying it (`size ()` and `get ()`)?** If it is necessary, how to synchronize these primitives as well and verify that `MySafeList` is functional for any value of `n` and `m` ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a synchronized list, use [`synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList-java.util.List-):

```
List<Double> mySafeList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

Be aware that iterations are not synchronized.

---

Or, if you want unsynchronized read access, at the cost of slower writes, use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html):

```
List<Double> mySafeList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, unless your aim is to understand the basic mechanism by coding them yourself.

Comment: So, with that after adding the synchronization primitives to the `add ()` method, it is not necessary to synchronize the methods that read the list without modifying it (`size ()` and `get ()`)?

Comment: If you're using synchronizedList, you do not need to synchronize any of add, size, get because synchronizedList is doing it for you.  In fact, it looks like your entire class MySafeList is not needed: just use a synchronizedList.   But whether you want that depends on your aims for writing this code.

Answer (score 1):

If there is code that can be modifying the list while other threads are reading it, then yes, you need synchronization - so that the list does not get modified while you are reading it.

The simplest way would be to add 'synchronized' to your 'add', 'get', and 'size' methods.

One can quibble about whether it's needed on 'size' but I think there's likely little gain to be had by omitting sync in that case, at least as you've written it here.

One unrelated point: why does your 'add' call return a hardwired 'true' value (making the return useless) rather than the value from the list's 'add'?   If you don't need to know whether an item was actually added, make it a void method.

Comment: This is not correct.  You need synchronization, period.  "Modifying the list while other threads are reading" isn't the whole picture.  The issue is visibility.  Writes (or other actions) are not guaranteed to be visible in Java's memory model unless both the read and the write are synchronized, and they have to be synchronized on the same lock/monitor.  Please refer to other posts on this subject, and also get a copy of Brian Goetz's *Java Concurrency in Practice,* it's really the best book on Java multithreading there is.

Comment: I thought this was the right approach at the beginning. Yet after reading @markspace comment, I'm confused. Second, my  'add' call return a hardwired 'true' as far as far as I had errors if I didn't. I'm going to double check that.

Comment: Oh, right. Your code extends ArrayList, so you'd want to preserve the semantics and signature of 'add'.  But hardwiring true is incorrect; you should return the result of the underlying 'add' call.

Comment: The class structure seems strange.  Your class extends ArrayList<> and yet there is a static ArrayList<>.   This means that after executing ```MySafeList x = new MySafeList()``` you've got two instances of an ArrayList, one sitting there mostly unused, except for all the methods you have not overridden.  This is going to be confusing, for example it is possible that size() will return non-zero and yet isEmpty() will say true, since you did not override that..

Comment: And then, if you also execute ```MySafeList y = new MySafeList(); // second list```, sometimes x and y are the same list (adds to x show up in y, and vice-versa), and sometimes they're not (any ArrayList method you did not override).